# Nhibernate .Fetch calls fail on a mocked session

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I love NHibernate (and NHibernate.Linq). I don't prematurely optimize, but sometimes I'll hit a really nasty N+1 issue. The recommended fix for the N+1 is to use NH's `Fetch` extension method.

The problem arises when I create a Mock of the `ISession`. I'll create a `List<User>` and set my mock to return the list whenever someone calls `_session.Query<User>()`. When I add a `Fetch` call to the query (i.e. `_session.Query<User>().Fetch(u => u.Address)`, I get the following error message:

```
There is no method 'Fetch' on type 'NHibernate.Linq.EagerFetchingExtensionMethods' 
that matches the specified arguments
```

NHibernate's fetch accepts a plain old `IQueryable<T>` but tries to cast it as specific NH implementations and fails if it can't.

I would really like `Fetch` to not error if it is called on a non-NH implementation (i.e. a list) and just be ignored so I can still use it in my unit tests. Help!

Answer (score 6):

Well, I tried to implement this myself, but thank god I found someone who already did the legwork.

http://mycodinglife.blog.com/2013/06/10/fetch-good-boy-now-play-nice-with-my-unit-tests/#

The only thing you have to do is call `EagerlyFetch` instead of just `Fetch`.

I've copied the relevant code below because his blog already has a fair amount of http 500 errors and css issues. I don't think it is being maintained.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using NHibernate.Linq;
using Remotion.Linq;

namespace LittleFish.Persistence.Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides extension method wrappers for NHibernate methods 
    /// to allow consuming source code to avoid "using" NHibernate.
    /// </summary>
    public static class NHibernateExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Eager-loads a projection of the specified queryable, 
        /// referencing a mapped child object.
        /// </summary>
        public static IFetchRequest<T, TRel> EagerlyFetch<T, TRel>(
            this IQueryable<T> queryable,
            Expression<Func<T, TRel>> expression)
        {
            if (queryable is QueryableBase<T>)
                return FetchHelper.Create(queryable.Fetch(expression));
            else
                return FetchHelper.CreateNonNH<T, TRel>(queryable);
        } 

        /// <summary>
        /// Eager-loads a second-level projection of the specified queryable, 
        /// referencing a mapped child of the first eager-loaded child.
        /// </summary>
        public static IFetchRequest<T, TRel2> ThenEagerlyFetch<T, TRel, TRel2>(
            this IFetchRequest<T, TRel> queryable,
            Expression<Func<TRel, TRel2>> expression)
        {
            if (queryable is QueryableFetchHelper<T, TRel>)
                return FetchHelper.CreateNonNH<T, TRel2>(queryable);
            else
                return FetchHelper.Create(queryable.ThenFetch(expression));
        } 

        /// <summary>
        /// Eager-loads a projection of the specified queryable, 
        /// referencing a mapped child object.
        /// </summary>
        public static IFetchRequest<T, TRel> EagerlyFetchMany<T, TRel>(
            this IQueryable<T> queryable,
            Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TRel>>> expression)
        {
            if(queryable is QueryableBase<T>)
                return FetchHelper.Create(queryable.FetchMany(expression));
            else
                return FetchHelper.CreateNonNH<T, TRel>(queryable);
        } 

        /// <summary>
        /// Eager-loads a second-level projection of the specified queryable, 
        /// referencing a mapped child of the first eager-loaded child.
        /// </summary>
        public static IFetchRequest<T, TRel2> ThenEagerlyFetchMany
            <T, TRel, TRel2>(
            this IFetchRequest<T, TRel> queryable,
            Expression<Func<TRel, IEnumerable<TRel2>>> expression)
        {
            if (queryable is QueryableFetchHelper<T, TRel>)
                return FetchHelper.CreateNonNH<T, TRel2>(queryable);
            else
                return FetchHelper.Create(queryable.ThenFetchMany(expression));
        }
    } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a wrapper for NHibernate's FetchRequest interface, 
    /// so libraries that run eager-loaded queries don't have to reference 
    /// NHibernate assemblies.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IFetchRequest<TQuery, TFetch> :
        INhFetchRequest<TQuery, TFetch>
    {
    } 

    internal class NhFetchHelper<TQuery, TFetch> : IFetchRequest<TQuery, TFetch>
    {
        private readonly INhFetchRequest<TQuery, TFetch> realFetchRequest;

        //this is the real deal for NHibernate queries
        internal NhFetchHelper(INhFetchRequest<TQuery, TFetch> realFetchRequest)
        {
            this.realFetchRequest = realFetchRequest;
        } 

        public IEnumerator<TQuery> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (realFetchRequest).GetEnumerator();
        } 

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (realFetchRequest).GetEnumerator();
        } 

        public Expression Expression
        {
            get { return (realFetchRequest).Expression; }
        } 

        public Type ElementType
        {
            get { return (realFetchRequest).ElementType; }
        } 

        public IQueryProvider Provider
        {
            get { return (realFetchRequest).Provider; }
        }
    } 

    internal class QueryableFetchHelper<TQuery, TFetch> :
        IFetchRequest<TQuery, TFetch>
    {
        private readonly IQueryable<TQuery> queryable;

        //for use against non-NH datastores
        internal QueryableFetchHelper(IQueryable<TQuery> queryable)
        {
            this.queryable = queryable;
        } 


        public IEnumerator<TQuery> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (queryable).GetEnumerator();
        } 

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (queryable).GetEnumerator();
        } 


        public Expression Expression
        {
            get { return (queryable).Expression; }
        } 

        public Type ElementType
        {
            get { return (queryable).ElementType; }
        } 

        public IQueryProvider Provider
        {
            get { return (queryable).Provider; }
        }
    } 

    /// <summary>
    /// The static "front door" to FetchHelper, with generic factories allowing 
    /// generic type inference.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class FetchHelper
    {
        public static NhFetchHelper<TQuery, TFetch> Create<TQuery, TFetch>(
            INhFetchRequest<TQuery, TFetch> nhFetch)
        {
            return new NhFetchHelper<TQuery, TFetch>(nhFetch);
        } 

        public static NhFetchHelper<TQuery, TFetch> Create<TQuery, TFetch>(
            IFetchRequest<TQuery, TFetch> nhFetch)
        {
            return new NhFetchHelper<TQuery, TFetch>(nhFetch);
        } 

        public static IFetchRequest<TQuery, TRel> CreateNonNH<TQuery, TRel>(
            IQueryable<TQuery> queryable)
        {
            return new QueryableFetchHelper<TQuery, TRel>(queryable);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetch is an extension method which comes from `NHibernate.Linq.EagerFetchingExtensionMethods` and that is why You can not mock it. If you accept the modification of the original production code, You can use a wrapper. Wrapper is the code which You will further mock!

Instead of calling Fetch in fluent way (`query.Fetch(...)`), You can call a wrapper and inject query as a reference:

```
NHibernateExtensionsWrapper.Fetch(query, x => x.ChildTable).ToList();
```

How to implement this wrapper?

```
public class NHibernateExtensionsWrapper : INHibernateExtensionsWrapper
{
    public INhFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated> Fetch<TOriginating, TRelated>(IQueryable<TOriginating> query,
        Expression<Func<TOriginating, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector)
    {
        return query.Fetch(relatedObjectSelector);
    }
}
```

How to implement a wrapper mock?

```
public class NHibernateExtensionsWrapperMock : INHibernateExtensionsWrapper
{
    public INhFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated> Fetch<TOriginating, TRelated>(IQueryable<TOriginating> query, Expression<Func<TOriginating, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector)
    {
        return (INhFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated>) new NhFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated>(query);
    }

    private class NhFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated> : INhFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated>
    {
        private readonly IQueryable<TOriginating> _query;

        public NhFetchRequest(IQueryable<TOriginating> query)
        {
            _query = query;
        }

        public IEnumerator<TOriginating> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _query.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public Expression Expression => _query.Expression;

        public Type ElementType => _query.ElementType;

        public IQueryProvider Provider => _query.Provider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a new workaround for this, because I didn't want to add a type check to every fetch call we used in production code or have to make changes around all the existing `.Fetch` calls.

The reason that `.Fetch` fails has to do with something internal to .NET that is rewriting the expression tree. I couldn't figure out exactly what was going on but it seemed to come down to the input given to the expression being `.List<T>` and it was checking the input matches using essentially `typeof(IQueryable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<T>))` which returns false.

I had already been using a wrapper instead of returning a plain `List<T>` (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42710376/7656736)) to fix an issue with `.ToFuture()` not working in unit tests.

From the linked answer code I added the following to `ExpressionTreeModifier`:

```
protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
{
    //Don't overwrite if fetch wasn't the method being called
    if (!node.Method.Name.Equals(nameof(EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.Fetch))
        && !node.Method.Name.Equals(nameof(EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.FetchMany))
        && !node.Method.Name.Equals(nameof(EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.ThenFetch))
        && !node.Method.Name.Equals(nameof(EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.ThenFetchMany)))
    {
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }

    //Get the first argument to the Fetch call. This would be our IQueryable or an Expression which returns the IQueryable.
    var fetchInput = node.Arguments[0];

    Expression returnExpression;

    switch (fetchInput.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.Constant:
            //If the input was a constant we need to run it through VisitConstant to get the underlying queryable from NHibernateQueryableProxy if applicable
            returnExpression = VisitConstant((ConstantExpression)fetchInput);
            break;
        default:
            //For everything else just return the input to fetch
            //This is covers cases if we do something like .Where(x).Fetch(x), here fetchInput would be another method call
            returnExpression = fetchInput;
            break;
    }

    return returnExpression;
}
```

What this does is rewrite the expression before it gets executed and completely removes the `Fetch` calls so we never end up with the Linq internals from trying to call it.