# Implementing a custom QueryProvider with in-memory query

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I'm trying to create a wrapper around [QueryableBase](https://github.com/re-motion/Relinq/blob/develop/Core/QueryableBase.cs) and [INhQueryProvider](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Linq/DefaultQueryProvider.cs#L13) that would receive a collection in the constructor and query it in-memory instead of going to a database. This is so I can mock the behavior of NHibernate's [`ToFuture()`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Linq/LinqExtensionMethods.cs#L85) and properly unit test my classes.

The problem is that I'm facing a stack overflow due to infinite recursion and I'm struggling to find the reason.

Here's my implementation:

```
public class NHibernateQueryableProxy<T> : QueryableBase<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
    public NHibernateQueryableProxy(IQueryable<T> data) : base(new NhQueryProviderProxy<T>(data))
    {
    }

    public NHibernateQueryableProxy(IQueryParser queryParser, IQueryExecutor executor) : base(queryParser, executor)
    {
    }

    public NHibernateQueryableProxy(IQueryProvider provider) : base(provider)
    {
    }

    public NHibernateQueryableProxy(IQueryProvider provider, Expression expression) : base(provider, expression)
    {
    }

    public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<T>>(Expression).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

internal class NhQueryProviderProxy<T> : INhQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryProvider provider;

    public NhQueryProviderProxy(IQueryable<T> data)
    {
        provider = data.AsQueryable().Provider;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return new NHibernateQueryableProxy<T>(this, expression);
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new NHibernateQueryableProxy<TElement>(this, expression);
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return provider.Execute(expression);
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return provider.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }

    public object ExecuteFuture(Expression expression)
    {
        return provider.Execute(expression);
    }

    public void SetResultTransformerAndAdditionalCriteria(IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhExpression, IDictionary<string, Tuple<object, IType>> parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*Edit:* I've kind of figured out the problem. One of the arguments to `expression` is my custom queryable. When this expression is executed by the provider, it causes an infinite call loop between `CreateQuery` and `Execute`. Is it possible to change all the references to my custom queryable to the queryable wrapped by this class?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, in the end I created my own `ToFuture` that called NH's `ToFuture` in production code and `ToList` in test code. But my guess is that you would need to write an expression visitor to replace the parameters by hand. That was actually my next try.

Comment: @CallumBradbury if you still need it, I think I've managed to mock it. Check the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a while I decided to give it another try and I guess I've managed to mock it. I didn't test it with real case scenarios but I don't think many tweaks will be necessary. Most of this code is either taken from or based on [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx). There are some caveats related to `IEnumerable` when dealing with those queries.

We need to implement `QueryableBase` since NHibernate [asserts the type](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/f648b00c5c1ca6d1487e15e458a5ef1af80c041b/src/NHibernate/Linq/LinqExtensionMethods.cs#L73) when using `ToFuture`.

```
public class NHibernateQueryableProxy<T> : QueryableBase<T>
{
    public NHibernateQueryableProxy(IQueryable<T> data) : base(new NhQueryProviderProxy<T>(data))
    {
    }

    public NHibernateQueryableProxy(IQueryProvider provider, Expression expression) : base(provider, expression)
    {
    }
}
```

Now we need to mock a `QueryProvider` since that's what LINQ queries depend on and it needs to implement `INhQueryProvider` because ToFuture() also [uses it](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/f648b00c5c1ca6d1487e15e458a5ef1af80c041b/src/NHibernate/Linq/LinqExtensionMethods.cs#L87).

```
public class NhQueryProviderProxy<T> : INhQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryable<T> _data;

    public NhQueryProviderProxy(IQueryable<T> data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    // These two CreateQuery methods get called by LINQ extension methods to build up the query
    // and by ToFuture to return a queried collection and allow us to apply more filters
    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        Type elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);

        return (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(NHibernateQueryableProxy<>)
                                    .MakeGenericType(elementType), new object[] { this, expression });
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new NHibernateQueryableProxy<TElement>(this, expression);
    }

    // Those two Execute methods are called by terminal methods like .ToList() and .ToArray()
    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return ExecuteInMemoryQuery(expression, false);
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        bool IsEnumerable = typeof(TResult).Name == "IEnumerable`1";
        return (TResult)ExecuteInMemoryQuery(expression, IsEnumerable);
    }

    public object ExecuteFuture(Expression expression)
    {
        // Here we need to return a NhQueryProviderProxy so we can add more queries
        // to the queryable and use another ToFuture if desired
        return CreateQuery(expression);
    }

    private object ExecuteInMemoryQuery(Expression expression, bool isEnumerable)
    {
        var newExpr = new ExpressionTreeModifier<T>(_data).Visit(expression);

        if (isEnumerable)
        {
            return _data.Provider.CreateQuery(newExpr);
        }

        return _data.Provider.Execute(newExpr);
    }

    public void SetResultTransformerAndAdditionalCriteria(IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhExpression, IDictionary<string, Tuple<object, IType>> parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The expression tree visitor will change the type of the query for us:

```
internal class ExpressionTreeModifier<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private IQueryable<T> _queryableData;

    internal ExpressionTreeModifier(IQueryable<T> queryableData)
    {
        _queryableData = queryableData;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
    {
        // Here the magic happens: the expression types are all NHibernateQueryableProxy,
        // so we replace them by the correct ones
        if (c.Type == typeof(NHibernateQueryableProxy<T>))
            return Expression.Constant(_queryableData);
        else
            return c;
    }
}
```

And we also need a helper (taken from the tutorial) to get the type being queried:

```
internal static class TypeSystem
{
    internal static Type GetElementType(Type seqType)
    {
        Type ienum = FindIEnumerable(seqType);
        if (ienum == null) return seqType;
        return ienum.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }

    private static Type FindIEnumerable(Type seqType)
    {
        if (seqType == null || seqType == typeof(string))
            return null;

        if (seqType.IsArray)
            return typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(seqType.GetElementType());

        if (seqType.IsGenericType)
        {
            foreach (Type arg in seqType.GetGenericArguments())
            {
                Type ienum = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(arg);
                if (ienum.IsAssignableFrom(seqType))
                {
                    return ienum;
                }
            }
        }

        Type[] ifaces = seqType.GetInterfaces();
        if (ifaces != null && ifaces.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (Type iface in ifaces)
            {
                Type ienum = FindIEnumerable(iface);
                if (ienum != null) return ienum;
            }
        }

        if (seqType.BaseType != null && seqType.BaseType != typeof(object))
        {
            return FindIEnumerable(seqType.BaseType);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

To test the above code, I ran the following snippet:

```
var arr = new NHibernateQueryableProxy<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).AsQueryable());

var fluentQuery = arr.Where(x => x > 1 && x < 4321443)
            .Take(1000)
            .Skip(3)
            .Union(new[] { 4235, 24543, 52 })
            .GroupBy(x => x.ToString().Length)
            .ToFuture()
            .ToList();

var linqQuery = (from n in arr
                    where n > 40 && n < 50
                    select n.ToString())
                    .ToFuture()
                    .ToList();
```

As I said, no complex scenarios were tested but I guess only a few tweaks will be necessary for real-world usages.

Comment: Wow, great job! I'll try implementing this on some of my stuff next time I get a chance

Comment: I got a chance to go back and try implementing this, and it works great! I had some issues with ToFutureValue, and had to write a custom implementation of IFutureValue<T> to deal with that, but apart from that it works like a charm :)

Comment: @CallumBradbury thanks for letting me know! If you want I can extend the solution to include the implementation you've made.